# Cannot find name 'setCometChat'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, cometchat

I'm facing an issue with initializing CometChat in a React application.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: Cannot find name 'setCometChat'. Did you mean 'CometChat'?
'CometChat' is declared here.
```

I have a `useEffect` for initialization:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  initCometChat();
  // ...
}, []);
```

And here's the `initCometChat` function:

```js
const initCometChat = async () => {
  const { CometChat } = await import('@cometchat-pro/cordova-ionic-chat');
  const appID = `${process.env.REACT_APP_COMETCHAT_APP_ID}`;
  const region = `${process.env.REACT_APP_COMETCHAT_REGION}`;
  const appSetting = new CometChat.AppSettingsBuilder().subscribePresenceForAllUsers().setRegion(region).build();
  CometChat.init(appID, appSetting).then(
    () => {
      console.log('CometChat was initialized successfully');
      setCometChat(() => CometChat);
    },
    error => {
    }
  );
};
```

I tried using the passed-in setter function like this:

```js
setCometChat(CometChat);
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with Ionic, but if I get it right, you are trying to set the current instance of `CometChat` to the variable `CometChat` that you have been using to initialize one. I suppose the error is occurring because `CometChat` has not been initialized as a state using `useState()` hook.

But in this case, setting the `CometChat` state to the variable `CometChat` that you use to initialize should not work. Maybe try separating the one that you are initializing and `CometChat` itself. What I mean is something like:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Component() {
  const [cometChatInitialized, setCometChatInitialized] = useState(null);

  const initCometChat = async () => {
    const { CometChat } = await import('@cometchat-pro/cordova-ionic-chat');
    // ...

    CometChat.init(appID, appSetting).then(
      () => {
        console.log('CometChat was initialized successfully');
        setCometChatInitialized(CometChat);
      },
      // ...
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Creating separate sections for the text makes the answer much easier to read. You can divide into sections by putting a an empty line between the sections (press enter key twice).